# Spring ResourceBundleMessageSource multiple properties files configuration in spring xml file?

Tags: spring

For example I am having two properties file like message and query. how can configure in the spring xml

Comment: Why not use @Bean definition?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the below code snippet.

```
    <context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:dao.properties,
    classpath:services.properties,
    classpath:user.properties"
    ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

1. In this, the order attribute needs to be specified to fix the order in which these are processed by Spring.
2. All property placeholders minus the last one (highest order) should have `ignore-unresolvable="true"` to allow the resolution mechanism to pass to others in the context without throwing an exception

Comment: I am getting below error message. 
Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'basename': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
 at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:289)
 at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:154)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:452)
 ... 30 more

Comment: Could you share the full stack trace here? Maybe the bean property is not matching with the property type.